# Nested template specialization depending on enclosing template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, nested-class, variadic-templates

```
template < int ...Indices>

class T1 {
    template <int _1, int _2>
    class T2;
};

template <int ...Indices>
template <int _1>
class T1<Indices...>::T2<_1, sizeof...(Indices)> {};
//^--error: non-type template argument depends on a template parameter of the partial specialization
```

compiles on gcc 4.5+ but neither on clang 3.1 nor icc, both complaining about the usage of `sizeof...(Indices)`.
Is it just a not-yet implemented feature in the latter compilers or some special case?

Thanks,

Buote

Comment: Looks like a bug in those compilers. If you can, try defining the nested template inside `T1`'s `class {}` block, perhaps delegating to a separate member template if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The standard says in [temp.class.spec] paragraph 8 that

> Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization, the following restrictions apply:
>   — A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple identifier. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>     template <int I, int J> struct A {};
>     template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {};  // error
>
>     template <int I, int J> struct B {};
>     template <int I> struct B<I, I> {};      // OK
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

The purpose of the rule is to disallow partial specializations based on non-trivial expressions like those in the example, and `sizeof...(Indices)` is *not* a simple identifier so maybe clang and ICC are right to reject it.  I'm not sure which compiler is right, to be honest.  I suggest reporting a bug to one of the compilers and if they say their implementation is correct report it to the others for interpreting it differently!

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to try:

```
template < int ...Indices>
class T1 
{
    static const int index_size = sizeof...(Indices);

    template <int _1, int _2>
    class T2;
};

template <int ...Indices>
template <int _1>
class T1<Indices...>::T2<_1, T1<Indices...>::index_size> {};
```

and see if the compiler issue is with the actual `sizeof...` operator, or if it's with the way it's being used in the template declaration.

Comment: That doesn't work either, so I guess they're both lacking the feature at the moment - as a workaround i just reversed my initial recursion order so that the partial specialization could be done for a constant value (e.g. 1).

Comment: As a sidenote, the intel compiler has some weird issues sometimes with the specialization of nested classes - making the corresponding declaration necessary inside the outer class' `{};` block instead of outside.